# I am working on a tableview tutorial and I don't understand some errors

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am new to Java and am working on a tutorial for the `TableView` and I don't understand some of the problems with the code.

I have the error message :

> the type of getColumns() is erroneous where S is a type-variable S
>   extends Object declared in class TableView

Thanks for any suggestions or help

Roger

```
table = new TableView<>();
data = getInitialTableData();
table.setItems(data);

TableColumn titleCol = new TableColumn("Title");
titleCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("title"));
TableColumn authorCol = new TableColumn("Author");
authorCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("author"));

table.getColumns().setAll(titleCol, authorCol);


table.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new RowSelectChangeListener());
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: What errors do you get? Please provide some more explanations of your code, what you are trying to do and what issue you are experiencing. Please read [How to create a *Minimal*, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and *improve your question*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of items you are trying to fill the `TableView` with, see the example in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html)

```
TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow through [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) tutorial from Oracle.

Your code has to be like:

```
TableColumn<Book,String> titleCol = new TableColumn<Book,String>("Title"); titleCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Book, String>("title"));
```

Best Improvement:

```
TableColumn<Book,String> titleCol = new TableColumn<>("Title"); titleCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("title"));
```